# Kafka Connect CDC to MSSQL "Table must have at least one primary key column"

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, cdc

I'm using Kafka Connect with MSSQL connector with a CDC enabled database and table. When creating the task with the REST API I receive the following error:

```
ERROR Exception thrown while querying for ChangeKey{databaseName=WebAppDb, schemaName=dbo, tableName=Companies} (io.confluent.connect.cdc.mssql.QueryService)
kafka-connect_1     | java.lang.IllegalStateException: Table([dbo].[Companies]) must have at least one primary key column.
kafka-connect_1     |   at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:197)
kafka-connect_1     |   at io.confluent.connect.cdc.mssql.MsSqlQueryBuilder.changeTrackingStatementQuery(MsSqlQueryBuilder.java:81)
kafka-connect_1     |   at io.confluent.connect.cdc.mssql.MsSqlQueryBuilder.changeTrackingStatement(MsSqlQueryBuilder.java:119)
kafka-connect_1     |   at io.confluent.connect.cdc.mssql.QueryService.queryTable(QueryService.java:117)
kafka-connect_1     |   at io.confluent.connect.cdc.mssql.QueryService.processTables(QueryService.java:92)
kafka-connect_1     |   at io.confluent.connect.cdc.mssql.QueryService.run(QueryService.java:67)
kafka-connect_1     |   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutionThreadService$1$2.run(AbstractExecutionThreadService.java:60)
kafka-connect_1     |   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Callables$3.run(Callables.java:95)
kafka-connect_1     |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What I don't understand is that this table has a primary key:

[image]

What can it be?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the reason for this is the name of the PK. Renaming to one without '.' character works. It should be a bug.